# FileField Paths works bad when upload image - the wrong way comes?

Tags: 7, files

I have my VPS with two sites: in first i have FileField Paths and it works bad. In second i have no FileFiled Paths and everything ok.

The error is this:

When I choose photo in the Image field and press "upload" it shows me blank image and when I open url address of this thumbnail - it shows 404. the thumbnail url is correct.

But the original image url is not corect. FileFiled paths make the original image url like this:

/system/temporary/filefield_paths/coctail-gold.jpg

but the pattern in Image field FileField paths settings is this:

blog_images/u[node:author:uid]/[current-date:custom:Y]

so this is the reasen why i see the blank image.

But when I save the post thumbnail shows correctly, so file creates.

Please what is wrong with FileField Paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Updated***

Assuming your installation code is not altered, I would suggest:

A.

1. Clear log messages at /admin/reports/dblog > "Clear log messages"
2. Try and re-upload your picture
3. Check your log messages reloading /admin/reports/dblog
   You should find here some diagnostic about your issue.

B.

1. Check your Status is nice and clear [ admin/reports/status ]

If nothing wrong so far, you should check [FileField Paths Issues](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/filefield_paths?categories=All) for similar issues, and eventually submit your experience. Drupal community will appreciate!

Hope will help.

Comment: sorry. but there i saw only autosave error like this https://www.drupal.org/node/2365769 but no anything about images

Comment: what about "admin/reports/status". Is there something left to do there?

Comment: i catch it just opening file link and it looks like: /system/temporary/filefield_paths/coctail-gold.jpg so the Filefield Paths works bad. in my other site on this VPS without filefield paths everything is good. but here it makes wrong path. path is setting in image field using File field paths like this: blog_images/u[node:author:uid]/[current-date:custom:Y]

Comment: That path seems very unusual.  What "admin/reports/status"  is saying?

Comment: only the message recommend swithc on updates manager. and the other things all right

Comment: i reproduce this configuration on shared hosting and it works fine there.  Please, why path on my vps becomes wrong?

Comment: From what I can understand, it should be related to file system permission (usually logged on dblog). I've updated my main answer, suggesting  to post an issue on the module page @drupal.org.

Comment: solved this: i had version File (Field) Paths rc. After update works fine. thank you

Comment: So, it was about then very beginning assumption **Assuming your installation code is not altered**. I guess you can vote up this answer?